# How do I pass on an image which will be selected from a group (on click) to anther html where it will be displayed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The first html will contain a slideshow of images from where the user will get to choose one on click. Then the user will be redirected to the next html in which the selected image will be displayed.

**This is my javascript code for the html where the image will be selected**

```js
var whichImages;

function displayImage(){

    document.getElementsByClassName("image").onclick = whichImages;
    return whichImages.join('');
}

sessionStorage.setItem(whichImages);
```

**This is my javascript code for the html where the selected image will be displayed**

```js
var mainChar = sessionStorage.getItem(whichImages);

function showImage2(){
  document.getElementById("img") = mainChar; 
}

showImage2();
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("image").onclick = whichImages;
return whichImages.join('');` what are you trying to do here? you need to pass an Event to the onclick, but your are trying to join it later, so you are passing an array?

Comment: Hello, I am relatively new to building websites so I will try to explain what I tried to do. I am trying to save an image in session storage that will be selected on click. Then I would like to display that image in the next page by accessing the session storage.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the behaviour you want. I changed to localStorage, so that is available if you open a new tab.

**select_images.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="see_images.html"> See selected images </a>
    </div>

    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/56866/garden-rose-red-pink-56866.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400"
      alt=""
    />
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4043324/pexels-photo-4043324.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400"
      alt=""
    />
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7003188/pexels-photo-7003188.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400"
      alt=""
    />
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6765585/pexels-photo-6765585.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400"
      alt=""
    />

    <script>
      //initializing with an empty array
      if (!localStorage.getItem("images")) {
        localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify([]));
      }

      //changed to local storage for it to work when opening a new tab
      //look in the local storage to see which images are saved, to apply the border to them (if page is refreshed)
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"))?.forEach((url) => {
        document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach((img) => {
          if (img.src == url) {
            img.style.border = "10px solid green";
          }
        });
      });

      //bind the click event on each img, if the img exists it will remove, if it doesn't exists, add it
      document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach((img) => {
        img.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          let imgSrcs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
          const currentImgSrc = e.currentTarget.src;

          if (imgSrcs.includes(currentImgSrc)) {
            const filtered = imgSrcs.filter((img) => img !== currentImgSrc);
            localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(filtered));
            e.currentTarget.style.border = "none";
            return;
          }

          imgSrcs.push(currentImgSrc);
          localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(imgSrcs));
          e.currentTarget.style.border = "10px solid green";
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**see_images.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="select_images.html"> Select Images </a>
    </div>

    <script>
      if (localStorage.getItem("images")) {
        const imgSrcs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));

        if (imgSrcs.length === 0) {
          document.body.append("No images selected");
        }

        imgSrcs.forEach((url) => {
          if (url) {
            const img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = url;
            document.body.append(img);
          }
        });
      } else {
        document.body.append("No images selected");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```